# Setting Grid width = "*" in Visual State Manager in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I am trying to build a UWP app that uses a Hub component to display 2 HubSections when in wide mode (default) and then to switch to showing only one HubSection when in Narrow mode

My HubSection is defined as follows:

```
    <Hub>
        <HubSection x:Name="Column1" Header="section 1" Background="Cornsilk">
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection x:Name="Column2" Header="section 2" Background="Chocolate">
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```

My Visual State Manager is defined like this:

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Column1.Width" Value="500" />
                    <Setter Target="Column2.Width" Value="700" />

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Column1.Width" Value="*" /> <--- This line doesn't work as * is not a number
                    <Setter Target="Column2.Width" Value="0" />

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The Question is how do I set the width of a component to * or "Use all space available" in the Visual State Manager?

Comment: A Hub  is probably not the right control to be using for this after reading the navigation guidelines here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure for HubControl, but I've done the same with a normal Grid ( to hide a column ).

Source here: https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/src/Kliva/Views/MainPage.xaml#L75

I needed to give the columndefinitions a name and use those in the visual state manager

Comment: Thanks. I have a had a rethink and don't think the Hub idea works best for this particular problem. I will switch to using a pivot control and reorganize the data a little better. Your answer would be the best way of achieving the above question though so I will accept the answer.